# Qual è il significato di "muretto" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Non c'era un'anima per le strade, noi stavamo asserragliati in casa Formosa, temendo una retata, spiando dalle finestre i movimenti dei tedeschi, che si erano arroccati nel cortile della scuola Giulio Cesare, assiepandola di mortai e mitragliatrici. 
>         Quando, ecco, dal portoncino del numero 43, vedemmo uscire, con la sigaretta spenta in bocca, la sagoma allampanata di Alberto Arbicone, uno dei decani del **muretto**.

Malgrado aver letto tutte le [accezioni di "muro" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/muro/), non riesco a capire il significato di "muretto" in questo brano. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il vezzeggiativo *muretto* è usato spesso per indicare un muro usato come luogo di ritrovo da un gruppo di giovani; spesso si tratta di un muro abbastanza basso da potercisi sedere sopra. Per esempio, una serie televisiva degli anni '90 era chiamata [*I ragazzi del muretto*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_ragazzi_del_muretto).

Comment: Condivido, a parte che io non vedo “muretto” usato direttamente per il “gruppo di giovani” ma solo per il loro luogo di ritrovo abituale. Se li incontrassi tutti insieme che passeggiano per strada, diresti “oggi ho visto passare il muretto”?

Comment: @DaG Hai ragione, giusta obiezione.

Comment: Hai ragione! Non ricordavo questo brano all'inizio del libro: *Spesso invece ci trovavamo in via Adige, nel quartiere Trieste dove alcuni di noi abitavano: una viuzza con un muretto che costeggia i cancelli, ricca di un suo fascino storico perché vi bazzicavano personaggi leggendari, di quattro o cinque anni maggiori di noi, ...*

Comment: Forse potresti modificare leggermente la risposta per tenere conto dell'obiezione di @DaG.

Comment: Vedo che l'hai già fatto.

Comment: Menzionerei il [muretto di Alassio](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muretto_di_Alassio)